# The new Husky Hooks is not working properly on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, yarnpkg, husky

I just started the project and followed the documentation (https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/), where I applied the following steps:

1. `npx husky-init && yarn # Yarn 1`
2. `npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"'`

After that, I edited the created file, **after command (2)**, looking like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

echo "HOOK PRE-COMMIT"

yarn lint-check
yarn prettier-check
```

Okay, after that I did two types of tests, which were:

1. With `prettier` + `eslint` applied throughout the project **(No error or warning)**
2. Without `prettier` + `eslint` applied throughout the project **(With warning)**

And in both tests, when committing the code, I always get the same error below:
[image]

What is happening?

**I use the following config:**

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- VSCode
- Yarn 1.22.11